# C++: Definition vs. Initialization vs. Assignment

Tags: c++

While reading learncpp.com's article on *[Switch fallthrough and scoping](https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/switch-fallthrough-and-scoping/)*, I came across teh following piece of code:

```cpp
switch (1)
{
    int a; // okay: definition is allowed before the case labels
    int b{ 5 }; // illegal: initialization is not allowed before the case labels

    case 1:
        int y; // okay but bad practice: definition is allowed within a case
        y = 4; // okay: assignment is allowed
        break;

    case 2:
        int z{ 4 }; // illegal: initialization is not allowed if subsequent cases exist
        y = 5; // okay: y was declared above, so we can use it here too
        break;

    case 3:
        break;
}
```

This made me wonder about the fundamental differences among variable definition, initialization and assignment.

```cpp
int foo; //variable definition
foo = 10; //assignment
int bar {20}; //variable initialization
```

From my prior understanding, defining a variable tells the compiler about the existence of the variable. Assigning the variable some value actually "assigns" a chunk of memory to the variable. Variable initialization using the uniform initialization (the curly braces) does both of these in one step.

If the above statements are true, then what is the reasoning behind not allowing the curly braces initialization but allowing definition followed by assignment?

In case my understanding is wrong, please correct me with the appropriate differences between these seemingly equivalent statements. I want to gain an understanding of what's going behind the scenes.

Comment: In the shown code, initialization is mandatory and assignment is not because it only happens if the shown code executes?

Comment: "Assigning the variable some value actually "assigns" a chunk of memory to the variable." No, it assigns a *value*, not a chunk of memory. "both of these" Initialisation (uniform or otherwise) is not assignment even if you disregard the declaration part. Initialisation turns raw memory into an object, while assignment mutates an existing object. In most cases they will have the same or similar effect, but for user defined types this is not a given.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI " Initialisation turns raw memory into an object" - this is new for me. Could you suggest some sources for further reading?

Comment: @Bob__ I had read this. My question is regarding my confusion about initialization, definition and assignment.

Comment: A definition associates a name with a type so the compiler knows if it needs to create space for the object if needed.  So in your example `int a;` tells the compiler that it will need to create an object of type `int` named `a`.

To initialize a variable is to provide a value for the defined object to be given.  `int foo{42};` defines a `int` named `foo` that will be initialized with the value of `42`.

To assign is to give an object a new value after it has already be defined.

Comment: One thing to note is that `T variable_name;` is called default initialization.  which means everything gets initialized.  it is just that for built in types, default initialization is no initialization.